# Javascript RegEx Lazy match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to find for loop pattern in javascript code, and replace syntax (from : to in), using below regex way,

```
var str="for(var x in []) for(var y in [])";

str.replace( new RegExp( '(for\\s*\\(.+\\s+):(\\s+.+\\))', 'ig' ), "\$1in\$2" )
```

i.e.

```
for(var x : list)
{
 // something
}
```

with

```
for(var x in list)
{
 // something
}
```

However I am facing issues when there are multiple for loops in same line.

```
for(var x : list) { for(var y : list) {
     // something
 }
}
```

which is valid syntax, however due to Greedy regex approach it converts as below:

```
for(var x : list) { for(var y in list) {
         // something
 }
}
```

I tried to explore lazy regex syntax but couldn't make it work. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Regex is no good for dealing with nested structures. I can make it work for current scenario but it may still fail in general when you have more nesting patterns.

Comment: Couldn't you just do it like `str.split(':').join(' in ')`? Or you only want to do it as part of for loops?

Comment: Icepickle, No, because ':' is used in various ways i.e. for objects ==> var objectA = {'A','Apple','B':'Banana'};

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshiHow shall I handle this thn ? Using recursive match ? Or any other possible way ?

Comment: @Pratik: Sorry, nesting doesn't seem an issue here. It can be easily done.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Can you please tell me how ?

Comment: @Pratik: Added as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965849/2102956) Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some lazy quantifiers to all `*` and `+`. and take `for` as part of the replacement, because of matching.

```js
var str = "for(var x : []) for(var y : [])";

console.log(str.replace(/for\s*?(\(.+?\s+?):(\s+?.+?\))/ig, "for $1in$2"));
```

A bit shorter and it includes `for` in the first group.

```js
var str = "for(var x : []) for(var y : [])";

console.log(str.replace(/(for\s*?\(.+?):(.+?\))/ig, "$1in$2"));
```

Comment: Writing `.+?\s+?` is redundant can be just written as `.+?` and same for `\s+?.+?`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using lazy quantifiers, you can use negated character set as they perform better and you can use this regex,

```
(for\s*\([^:]+):([^)]+\))
```

and replace it with,

```
$1 in $2
```

Also, you don't have to use `.+\\s+` as this is redundant and instead you can just write `.+?` and even better to use negated character set for it to work faster and similarly after `:` you can write `\\s+.+` as `.+?` but again negated character class is better choice like I mentioned in my answer.

Another point that could lead you into issues is, you should not use this `\$1in\$2` for replacement, and instead use `$1 in $2` firstly you don't need to escape `$` as `\$` and secondly because in case your for loop is like this, `for(var x:list)` i.e. without having space between colon and surrounding variables, then the output of replacement you may get is `for(var xinlist)` which would make it invalid. Which is why I suggested above in my answer to replace with `$1 in $2` so `in` has space at both sides.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/td8Du2/1)**

JS codes,

```js
const s = `for(var x : list)
{
 // something
}

for(var x : list) { for(var y : list) {
     // something
 }
}`

console.log(s.replace(/(for\s*\([^:]+):([^)]+\))/g, '$1 in $2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The lazy behaviour can be achived with a `?` after the quantifier.

```
const str = "for(var x : list) { for(var y : list) {"
str.replace( new RegExp( '(for\\s*?\\(.+?\\s+?):(\\s+.+\\))', 'ig' ), "\$1in\$2" )
```

btw. JavaScript RegEx literals are much easier to read:

```
str.replace( /(for\s*?\(.+?\s+?):(\s+.+\))/ig, "\$1in\$2" )
```

Comment: "achieve using" what?